# what does .htaccess with line AddHandler php5-script .php do?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am with new web host. The public_html folder of each domain I create is auto generated with an .htaccess that has the following line:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

What is this for?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This just instructs PHP to handle files ending in `.php` by passing them to the PHP5 interpreter.  Without this configuration in place, the web server may serve the files to the end-user's web browser as raw PHP code, rather than executing the code.  That raises the dangerous possibility  of exposing database login credentials or, or other secrets.

Using the same mechanism, you could configure the web server to parse files with other extensions besides `.php` as PHP scripts and hand them to the PHP interpreter.  This is occasionally done to mask PHP scripts by naming them with `.html` extensions, for example.

```
# Interpret both .php & .html as PHP:
AddHandler php5-script .php .html
```

Comment: 4 years later and I am wondering wether this is necessary even if I have this rule in my apache configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

It tells php to handle *any file* with .php in the filename, *even if it's not at the end*. A file named smile.php.gif will be interpereted as a php file, which is bad if you are going to be using an upload script. This is because Apache allows multiple extensions in any order, so gif.php.jpg is the same as gif.jpg.php. I have heard the best way to select the handler is with FilesMatch. Of course if your web host has this in their httpd.conf you would have to 'remove' it using your htaccess before using the FilesMatch if you don't have access to httpd.conf.

Comment: It is vulnerable for uploading files, i.e: file.php.png, we can bypass and attack the website by uploading a file named shell.php.png

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the htaccess tells the webserver to handle the `php` as `php5-script` and execute it.

> Regarding the first answer, you will achieve your goal but it is a really bad practice and you should not allow `html` files to be executed as `php` due to huge security concerns.